# Error showing up when using multicolumn and colors

Tags: tables, color, multicolumn

I have a document that is creating the exact output I'm looking for, yet when I compile it I'm getting two errors. After tooling around for a little bit, I was able to pinpoint their location to the `\multicolumn` commands in my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|P{9cm}P{9cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\large \rowcolor{black} \color{white} {\bf Testing Modifications (highlight or circle)}} \\ 
\hline
Time Limit Waved         & On-Task Focusing Prompts \\
Exam/Sep Location        & Waive Spelling Reqs \\
Questions Read Aloud     & Revise Test Format \\
Answers Any Way          & Revise Test Directions \\
Calc/Abacus Permitted    & Breaks \\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\AddLabel Other:} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\[.4cm]

{\bf \underline{PRESENT LEVELS OF PERFORMANCE}} \\[.4cm]

\begin{tabular}{|p{4.25cm}|p{4.25cm}|p{4.25cm}|p{4.25cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\large \rowcolor{black} \color{white} {\bf Evaluation Results}} \\ 
\hline
& & & \\[1.2cm]
\hline
\end{tabular} \\[.4cm]
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign
```

Since the output doesn't seem to be affected, it hasn't been bothering me all that much, but I definitely am curious as to why this error is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use `\rowcolor` at the start of a row, use `\cellcolor` or or `\multicolumn{4}{|>{\columncolor{black}}c|}` or (if you have the latest colortbl) put `\rowcolor` first before the `\multicolumn`

Unrelated but `\bf` has been deprecated in LaTeX since LaTeX2e was released, it is much better to use `\bfseries`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help!

And I switched all the `\bf` portions of my code to `\bfseries`, and will use the latter from here on out! Thanks for taking the time to provide some guidance!